# pToast se duplica en componente padre y en modal con conponente hijo

Tags: angular, modal, primeng, dialog

tengo un componente padre llamado consulta, en el cual se estan mostrando las notificaciones de pToast de mis componentes hijos los cuales estan dentro de un dialog (modal de primeng).
Hay alguna forma de prevenir que las notificaciones se muestren solamente dentro del dialog y no en el componente de consulta (el cual queda de fondo al momento de abrir la modal)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usando *key* en el toast para validar cual notificación debe mostrarse, forzar usando la propiedad para no duplicarse y mostrarse encima si le indicas el valor correcto en *ZIndex*.

```
<p-toast key="myKey1" appendTo="body" baseZIndex="2" preventOpenDuplicates="true"></p-toast>

this.messageService.add({
    key: 'myKey1', 
    severity:'success', 
    summary: 'Summary Text', 
    detail: 'Esta notificación solo se mostrará donde toast key = myKey1'
});
```